# Save Expected_output(buffer) into a file - Bash

Tags: bash, shell, expect

I have this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter IP Address: " ip
read -p "login: " user
read -p "password: " password

/usr/bin/expect<<EOF
spawn telnet ${ip}
expect "login"
send "${user}\n"
expect -re "password"
send "${password}\n"
expect ">"
send "show system\r"
expect ">"
send "show interfaces 6/2 counters\r"
expect ">"
send "exit\r"
expect ">"
sleep 2
exit
EOF
```

and I'm trying to save value returned by commands "show system" and "show interfaces 6/2 counters" in a file called Logs.txt in my home directory.

In bash I use

```
echo "Date creation $(date)" >> ~/ls.txt
echo >> ~/ls.txt
echo "show system output" >> ~/ls.txt
echo Hello >> ~/ls.txt
echo >> ~/ls.txt
echo "output" >> ~/ls.txt
echo Hello2 >> ~/ls.txt
```

How can I do the same into an expect script?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
I need to append two outputs not override.

Answer (score 1):

```
set prompt "\r\n(.*?)>"
spawn telnet ${ip}
expect "login"
send "${user}\r"
expect -re "password"
send "${password}\r"
expect ">"
send "show system\r"
expect -re $prompt
# Extracting the 1st substring
lappend result expect_out(1,string);
send "show interfaces 6/2 counters\r"
expect -re $prompt
# Extracting the 1st substring
lappend result expect_out(1,string)
```

You can write it to the file as,

```
set fp [open output w]
puts $fp $result
close $fp
```

Comment: Thanks you, I'll try your solution